# Get Total From a Chosen Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanted to get the total `productPrice` from the `chosenData` array. I need to compare it from the `mainData` and only get its total value. My problem is that I'm getting undefined and how should I do it and is there a shorter way of doing it?

```js
  const mainData = [
    {
        "id": "4324",
        "productName": "Apple",
        "productPrice": 250,
    },
    {
        "id": "656546b",
        "productName": "Banana",
        "productPrice": 500,
    },
    {
        "id": "5656",
        "productName": "Soup",
        "productPrice": 800,
    }
];

const chosenData = ['5656', '656546b']
  
  const newArray = chosenData.map((value, index) => ({
    productPrice: mainData.find((data) => data.id === value)
  }))


console.log(newArray.productPrice)
```

Comment: `newArray` is an Array. Arrays don’t have `productPrice` properties. Look at the `newArray` object itself (e.g. by logging it). You’re close. Returning an object with the `productPrice` property inside the `map` is not useful — the objects in `mainData` already have this property; no need to add yet another layer. The `find` is correct. All you need to do now is to sum by property, e.g. with `reduce`. See [Better way to sum a property value in an array](/q/23247859/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution, newArray obtained through map is an array, and array does not have the attribute `productPrice`, therefore you got undefined.

You can filter out the object with matching id, then sum them up, ex:

```
mainData.filter(value=>chosenData.includes(value.id)).reduce((acc, cur)=>acc+cur.productPrice, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` returns a new array and it does not skip any element. You can use `reduce` and inside the reduce callback, use `find`. If an element with same id is found in the maindData it will return the object otherwise undefined. If it is not undefined , then get the value and accumulate it.

```js
const mainData = [{
    "id": "4324",
    "productName": "Apple",
    "productPrice": 250,
  },
  {
    "id": "656546b",
    "productName": "Banana",
    "productPrice": 500,
  },
  {
    "id": "5656",
    "productName": "Soup",
    "productPrice": 800,
  }
];

const chosenData = ['5656', '656546b']

const newArray = chosenData.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  const findById = mainData.find(item => item.id === curr);
  findById && (acc += findById.productPrice)
  return acc;

}, 0)


console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `newArray` is an array. You can't access its property like `newArray.productPrice`. You want to compute a value from your newArray, so you can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Building up on your code

```js
const mainData = [
    {
        "id": "4324",
        "productName": "Apple",
        "productPrice": 250,
    },
    {
        "id": "656546b",
        "productName": "Banana",
        "productPrice": 500,
    },
    {
        "id": "5656",
        "productName": "Soup",
        "productPrice": 800,
    }
];

const chosenData = ['5656', '656546b']
  
  const newSum = chosenData.map((value, index) => ({
    productPrice: mainData.find((data) => data.id === value)
  })).reduce((agg,x) => {
  return agg + x.productPrice.productPrice
  },0);


console.log(newSum)
```

If you don't want to complicate with too many properties you can use this code:

```js
const mainData = [
    {
        "id": "4324",
        "productName": "Apple",
        "productPrice": 250,
    },
    {
        "id": "656546b",
        "productName": "Banana",
        "productPrice": 500,
    },
    {
        "id": "5656",
        "productName": "Soup",
        "productPrice": 800,
    }
];

const chosenData = ['5656', '656546b']
  
  const newSum = chosenData.map((value, index) => mainData.find((data) => data.id === value).productPrice).reduce((agg,x) => agg + x,0);


console.log(newSum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `newArray` is an array of products filtered. Map returns an array. Probably try to `reduce` it to calculate the `productPrice` total or something. But the code is wrong at `newArray.productPrice`

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce `mainData` and get `totalPrice` with O(n)

```js
const mainData = [
    {
        "id": "4324",
        "productName": "Apple",
        "productPrice": 250,
    },
    {
        "id": "656546b",
        "productName": "Banana",
        "productPrice": 500,
    },
    {
        "id": "5656",
        "productName": "Soup",
        "productPrice": 800,
    }
];

const chosenData = ['5656', '656546b']
  
const totalPrice = chosenData.reduce((acc, {id, productPrice}) => {
    if (chosenData.includes(id)) {
        acc += productPrice;
    }
    return acc;
}, 0)


console.log(totalPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
const newArray = chosenData.map(value => mainData.find(data => data.id === value).productPrice)

console.log(newArray.productPrice)
```

Comment: Can you explain your code, and why your answer should fix the issue ? Please [edit] your answer :)